# Agora crash in the TestFlight

Tags: react-native, expo, agora.io

I am assembling the application with the help of EXPO

my code in App.tsx:

```
import 'expo-dev-client';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AgoraUIKit from 'agora-rn-uikit'; 
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [videoCall, setVideoCall] = useState(true);
    const props = {
        connectionData: {
            appId: 'db75cb2a42d84324bae3a93125e0422d',
            channel: 'test',
        },
        rtcCallbacks: {
            EndCall: () => setVideoCall(false),
        },
    };

    return videoCall ? (
    <AgoraUIKit connectionData={props.connectionData} rtcCallbacks={props.rtcCallbacks} />
    ) : null;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Crash Feedback in the TestFlight:

Incident Identifier: 473A2BF0-12DB-424B-80D2-D1E787C432E1
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,1
Process:             myapp [16018]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FB254B9-48F1-4155-ABCE-FF1089171885/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:          com.fgf.binaryrocks
Version:             1.3.18 (1.0.3)
AppStoreTools:       14B44
AppVariant:          1:iPhone9,1:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.fgf.binaryrocks [731]

Date/Time:           2022-11-25 13:37:23.5577 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-11-25 13:37:23.3366 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6.1 (19G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    9.61.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18060fd1c _*exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x197e2fee4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   myapp                           0x100329d70 RCTFatal + 568 (RCTAssert.m:147)
3   myapp                           0x10039cfcc -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] + 476 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:77)
4   myapp                           0x10039d810 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1292 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:147)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x18059ddd0 **invoking*** + 144 (:-1)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1805b9ea8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1805ee2cc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 76 (NSForwarding.m:3475)
8   myapp                           0x100357df4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 388 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   myapp                           0x100359f6c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 452 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  myapp                           0x100359bf4 facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
11  myapp                           0x100359bf4 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1802cf094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1802d0094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x18027673c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1802771f4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408 (queue.c:3944)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x180280ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db95ce10 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db95c93c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed4aac mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed507c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180583d88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180588090 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018059b250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001a10c6988 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d9ba94 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3511)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b34fd4 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
8   myapp                           0x00000001002951f0 main + 80 (main.m:7)
9   dyld                            0x00000001008d84d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c934 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baedabbc __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db968854 pthread_kill + 208 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018acf96ac abort + 124 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197f27dd8 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197f1855c demangling_terminate_handler() + 300 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197e358f8 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197f27274 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197f2721c std::terminate() + 60 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001802d00a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018027673c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001802771f4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408 (queue.c:3944)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180280ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95ce10 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c93c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c934 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed4aac mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed507c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180583d88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180588090 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018059b250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181ca8eec -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181ce8000 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d1af00 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181cf5bfc **NSThread__start** + 792 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95e348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c948 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c934 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c934 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1f3058 JSStringRelease + 32 (atomic:1083)
1   myapp                           0x00000001003ecf54 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const + 204 (JSCRuntime.cpp:1403)
2   myapp                           0x00000001003ee8e8 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getValueAtIndex(facebook::jsi::Array const&, unsigned long) + 84 (JSCRuntime.cpp:1047)
3   myapp                           0x00000001003f5568 facebook::jsi::Array::getValueAtIndex(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, unsigned long) const + 28 (jsi-inl.h:220)
4   myapp                           0x00000001003f5568 facebook::jsi::dynamicFromValue(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) + 524 (JSIDynamic.cpp:175)
5   myapp                           0x00000001003f84d4 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::jsi::Value const&, bool) + 80 (JSIExecutor.cpp:419)
6   myapp                           0x00000001003f7c10 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, st... + 412 (JSIExecutor.cpp:269)
7   myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 std::__1::__function::__value_func<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*&&) const + 24 (function.h:505)
8   myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const + 24 (function.h:1182)
9   myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8::operator()() const + 48 (NativeToJsBridge.cpp:310)
10  myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 decltype(static_cast<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&>(fp)()) std::__1::__invoke<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridg... + 48 (type_traits:3918)
11  myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8&>(facebook::react... + 48 (invoke.h:61)
12  myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeTo... + 48 (function.h:178)
13  myapp                           0x00000001003eb2e0 std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBrid... + 60 (function.h:352)
14  myapp                           0x00000001003457f8 std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (function.h:505)
15  myapp                           0x00000001003457f8 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (function.h:1182)
16  myapp                           0x00000001003457f8 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 32 (RCTCxxUtils.mm:74)
17  myapp                           0x0000000100350874 facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 24 (RCTMessageThread.mm:69)
18  myapp                           0x0000000100350628 std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (function.h:505)
19  myapp                           0x0000000100350628 std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (function.h:1182)
20  myapp                           0x0000000100350628 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>) + 44 (RCTMessageThread.mm:45)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001805ea74c **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 20 (CFRunLoop.c:1820)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001805eb570 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 408 (CFRunLoop.c:1862)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180587ef8 __CFRunLoopRun + 752 (CFRunLoop.c:2949)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018059b250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
25  myapp                           0x000000010033b84c +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 212 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:335)
26  Foundation                      0x0000000181cf5bfc **NSThread__start** + 792 (NSThread.m:972)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95e348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c948 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed5484 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db964bd4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ae8a154 scavenger_thread_main + 1120 (pas_scavenger.c:135)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95e348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c948 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001baed5484 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db964bd4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018adeea64 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1984 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018adb68ec bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUncheckedWTF::Lock(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 176 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018adb6d3c WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 328 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ae0ead4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 336 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ae10dac WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95e348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db95c948 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x0000000197f2aea1   x5: 0x000000016fc82420   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffb5dc
x8: 0x000000016fc83000   x9: 0xe43a2ddff38421c7  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000001  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x0000000000001803  x21: 0x000000016fc830e0  x22: 0x000000016fc830e0  x23: 0x0000000283111630
x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000114  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
x28: 0x0000000280a0f940   fp: 0x000000016fc82390   lr: 0x00000001db968854
sp: 0x000000016fc82370   pc: 0x00000001baedabbc cpsr: 0x40000000
esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x100290000 - 0x1004d3fff myapp arm64  <4620a0f623323b5a9b4901fd182135c9> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FB254B9-48F1-4155-ABCE-FF1089171885/myapp.app/myapp
0x1008c0000 - 0x100913fff dyld arm64   /usr/lib/dyld
0x18026c000 - 0x1802eefff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <4fc02901034e35cf8cf25b7f81d579e4> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18057d000 - 0x1809bafff CoreFoundation arm64  <55a96cfe31413f568ab1569c607b9370> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x181c91000 - 0x181f75fff Foundation arm64  <3fe3654abb333073a53a563ff81c1dd0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1828b6000 - 0x184051fff UIKitCore arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x18acda000 - 0x18ad55fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <888f81bafb993ea79e300cf73bab720f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18ada9000 - 0x18c128fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <39a6a7841b333630b400b3f5fa2ddcfe> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x197e1b000 - 0x197e52fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x197f17000 - 0x197f2dfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <315a3f290b9c3e29b855f6c0958859fd> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1a10c5000 - 0x1a10cdfff GraphicsServices arm64  <99e76e47eaad3c2ab6cdc3bd3824fe8c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1baed4000 - 0x1baf07fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <14abffc1c15e3c93a655a917279db06c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1db95b000 - 0x1db96bfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <9890465bab703de38d35adfd1441b7fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF

I tried to do the documentation,  [agora with expo](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-a-video-calling-app-using-the-agora-sdk-on-expo-react-native/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only on iOS, I fixed it by adding `rtcUid` (as a number) instead of `uid` as in the documentation.

```js
connectionData: {
   appId: 'db75cb2a42d84324bae3a93125e0422d',
   channel: 'test',
   rtcUid: myUid
   token,
}
```